# Making a method a @staticmethod for documentation purposes?

Tags: python, coding-style, static-methods

I sometimes use the `@staticmethod` decorator to indicate that a method only depends on its arguments and doesn't touch the instance (i.e. `self`). My intention is to document that  the method is indeed a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function). Is this usage of static methods advisable or should I just include such information in the docstring?

I do know what `@staticmethod` does (changed signature, ...). I'm not interested in its mechanics. I want to know if it's good style to make methods static any time they don't really need `self` at all (basically as documentation of that fact).

Comment: `@staticmethod` is different from purity: `@staticmethod` just means the function doesn't require an instance as the first (hidden) argument; purity prohibits side-effects, so you're not allowed to tamper with global variables nor do any I/O.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Definitely use `@staticmethod` if you actually have a static method.

`@staticmethod` does more than just document your intention, it actually changes the behavior of your method.  It stops the first variable of the method being bound to the instance.

With `@staticmethod`:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     @staticmethod
...     def bar(argument):
...         print argument
...
>>> foo = Foo('foo')
>>> foo.bar(1)
1
```

Without `@staticmethod`:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __init__(self, name):
...         self.name = name
...     def bar(argument):
...         print argument
...
>>> foo = Foo('foo')
>>> foo.bar(1) # the 'argument' variable is bound to the instance, so you're now sending two arguments to this method
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: bar() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)
```

If what you have is a static method, you should use `@staticmethod` and omit `self` in the method signature.
If you're not using `@staticmethod` you *must* (by convention) use `self` in the method signature, and not use it anywhere in the method - but why would you do this?

**Edit:** For some reason I missed the bit about pure functions.  Static methods != pure functions, you can have static methods that are impure (e.g. include a print statement or mutate a list that gets sent in as an argument) and instance methods that are pure (they use but don't alter the value of instance attributes *Further edit: Only if the instance attributes in question are immutable*).  `@staticmethod` is a near-essential line of code for a static method, but is poor documentation to denote the purity of a method.  If purity is what you want to specifically document, then you're right, you should put it in the docstring.

Another question to consider is - why have a static method instead of a function unbound to an object?  If the function must be a method, then it really ought to be a static method.  But in Python, you may be better off making it just a standalone function.